# symfony 5.4 An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'username' cannot be null

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony5.4

i am using **friendsofsymfony** bundle for authentication, the scenario is when i try to login, the user logged in successfully and getting access token, but in same request when some security events triggered and try to update lastLogin column in user table i am getting above error.

**this error came out after upgrading symfony from 4.3 to 5.4**

scurity file:

```
security:
password_hashers:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface:
        algorithm: auto
        cost: 13

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        user_checker: security.user_checker
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
        remember_me:
            secret:   '%kernel.secret%'
            lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
            path:     /


access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: '%env(X-FORWARDED-PROTO)' }
    ......


imports:
- { resource: 'role_hierarchy.yaml' }
```

composer.json packages that I have installed:

```
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "2.7.2",
"doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "3.2.4",
"doctrine/orm": "2.15.3",
"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "3.2.1",
```

Answer (score 0):

*maybe you have two choice :*

**1**. you are trying to insert/update row in database but username sent without value, try to **dump** username variable and check the value

**2**. change security bundle, from **FOSUserBundle** to **SecurityBundle** (in 5.4 version)

Answer (score 0):

Solution in my case:
In User Entity the properties must be same with FOS UserInterface, so i solved it by checking common properties (username,email,password and ..etc) make them exactly same.